# Where do we deploy our dynamic web application? In WebServer or AppServer?

Tags: servlets, server-side

Let's say we have developed a dynamic web application which includes JSP's, servlets, DB connections etc. In which server do we deploy that application, a web Server or an App Server.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't deploy a java web-application on web-server.

you have to deploy java web-app to an application server (i.e. Wildfly, TomEE, JBoss EAP) or servlet container.

Now, The actual question arises that if you want directly configure the application server to serve request or configure a web server as a reverse proxy to forward requests to the application server.

Actually, it all depends on your needs. Some question you should ask yourself regarding your project requirements.

- Do I need a load balancer to handle?
- Do I need better web security?
- Deployment of other websites and web application on the same physical server?

if yes, then you should go for a web server like apache HTTPd or Nginx.

Comment: if we cannot deploy a web application on a web server, how are we able to run our basic dynamic web applications on a tomcat server in eclipse?
Is tomcat a web server or an app server?

Comment: application server.

Comment: if tomcat is an application server, why can't we run EJB on tomcat? Why do we need something like JBOSS